# How can an Omni-Channel Notification be invoked when Case Re-Opened (but not re-assigned)

Tags: servicecloud, omnichannel

When a previously closed case is re-opened, we would like the case to get pushed to the existing case owner in the same way a new case does. They key here is getting a notification through Omni-Channel so that the agent doesn't have to remember to go back to their personal queue and check for re-opened cases.

Simply re-opening a case does not invoke a notification. Changing the owner to a non-omnichannel queue and then re-assigning back to the original owner does not invoke a notification either. Re-opening the case and assigning to an omni-channel queue does cause a notification....however, we want the case to stay with the currently assigned owner/agent, not to get re-assigned.

We are happy to use any combination of workflow and apex to invoke the notification.

Comment: Would adding the record to AgentWork ensure, the next case pushed to the agent (when the status becomes Available) is the reopened case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create an [AgentWork](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_agentwork.htm) record through APEX for a agent. This what normal Omni-Channel routing does, so it causes all of the normal notifications and auto-push behaviour.